# Java class that takes two strings and returns indices of characters that differ

Tags: java, diff

Instead of writing my own implementation, I am looking for a Java class that can find the differences in two strings of text.

Ideally, I would like the method to take two strings of text, and return a list of indices of where the strings differ from eachother.

Does anyone know of such a class?

Comment: You can see if Apache commons StringUtils# indexOfDifference() can be of any use !

Comment: Yikes! Downvoters, care to explain?

Comment: I'm guessing writing a simple `for` loop and returning a  `List<Integer>` is too difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `commons-lang` from Apache, especially `StringUtils` class that contains many of usefull String methods : 
[commons.apache.org](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

i.e, there's the `getLevenshteinDistance` that gives the distance between two Strings. Or `indexOfDifference` that returns the index of the first different character.

Comment: +1 Very helpful. Thanks. (Waiting on more answers before accepting...)